# JSViews computed observable linked to <select> not updating with .set()

Tags: jsviews, computed-observable

I am trying to link a `<select>` box to a computed observable object in JSViews. The `<select>` updates fine when the depended upon variable changes. However when selecting a new value in the `<select>` box it does not trigger the set() function I defined. See https://jsfiddle.net/4y274h0L/3/

**Template**

```
<select>
    {{for options}}
        <option value="{{:#data}}" data-link="{:#data} selected{:~root.computedSelectedOption() == #data}"></option>
    {{/for}}
</select>
```

**Computed observable**

```
function privateComputedOption() {
    return vm.tempSelectedOption;
}

privateComputedOption.depends = ["~root.tempSelectedOption"];

privateComputedOption.set = function(val) {
    $.observable(vm).setProperty("tempSelectedOption", val);
    console.log(val);
};
```

Any help would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually data-link the select to the computed observable. For two-way bindings it is the binding on the select that will call the setter when the user changes the drop-down selection.

```
<select data-link="computedSelectedOption()">
  {{for options}}
    <option value="{{:#data}}"
     data-link="{:#data} selected{:~root.computedSelectedOption()==#data}">  
    </option>
  {{/for}}
</select>

{^{:computedSelectedOption()}}
```

I updated the jsfiddle as above:

https://jsfiddle.net/4y274h0L/4/

See for example http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/form-els/array-binding.

BTW in the next update of JsViews things will be simplified and you will not need to data-link to `selected{:~root.computedSelectedOption()==#data}"` on the options. Just the data-link on the select `<select data-link="computedSelectedOption()">` will suffice.

Comment: Thanks! That was it indeed. In the real code I still used an old reference to the non-computed value.. So I did have a data-link in the select but it was another viewmodel property.